# Silverlight PollingDuplexHttpBinding and cross domain issues

Tags: silverlight, cross-domain, polling, duplex

I created a silverlight component and a WCF service, both are communicating using a PollingDuplexHttpBinding to enable push and pull functionality.

Works perfectly in our domain, however, a host outside our domain makes completly no calls to the webservice which is publicly exposed.

clientaccesspolicy file is available and downloadable from the root, I even added a crossdomain file. So from server A to server B (A and B in same domain) I see the post requests from the silverlight client (in FireBug), between from A and C (where C is an external server), there no calls, even not to the clientaccesspolicy file.

Is a PollingDuplexHttpBinding and cross domain still posible (cannot find anything about this) or is there something else I can look at?